# How to get karate executable jar file without changing the project structure?

Tags: karate

I am doing API Automation testing using karate framework. I have multiple APIs(around 300) and project is bit complex which consists of multiple folder where data flows from 1 feature files to another. I used karate executable jar file to run few feature files. But my client requirement is to generate executable jar file without changing the project structure and run the jar in server. Can anyone help me?

Thanks